# Very weird behaviour destroys my robot and makes it fly around

Tags: collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I generated an sdf from a urdf for robot (urdf fully functional while using the real robot)
Can somebody give me some hints about what might be the cause of [this weird behaviour](https://youtu.be/_eonQ9T9n4o)?

If you need to understand what the robot exactly is you can watch [this video](https://youtu.be/64S5I_VpA1Q)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8640/very-weird-behaviour-destroys-my-robot-and-makes-it-fly-around/) by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 94 on 2015-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Apparently something was wrong with internal collisions. I had a script that automatically transformed urdf to sdf but I guess it didn't work that good. I am now loading urdf directly to Gazebo and it seems that the problem is solved.

---

Originally posted by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) with karma: 94 on 2015-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AReimann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1170/areimann/) on 2015-05-14**:
Was the script the official urdf -> sdf generator?

**Comment by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) on 2015-05-15**:
@Alex No it was a script my colleague wrote for another simple robot but it turned out it didn't work very well causing a lot of internal collisions. Spawning a robot directly from an URDF was also simpler with Gazebo.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Maybe you can try some of the different visualization options (Collision, Inertia, Joints, Contacts) to give more clues about what might be wrong?

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2015-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2